# Why is my output partially BiDi?

Tags: xetex, hebrew, bidi

I'm using xelatex (on Debian stable).

My TeX file looks like this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam CLM}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \begin{hebrew} לורם איפסום דולור סיט אמט \end{hebrew}
\end{document}
```

My output looks like:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, אמט סיט דולור אפסום לורם

So it's BiDi in that the letters are in the correct order, but for some reason the words are read left to right.

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

For inline Hebrew, you should use `\texthebrew`. The `hebrew` environment is for paragraph text.

```
%!TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{bidi}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Noto Sans Hebrew}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \texthebrew{לורם איפסום דולור סיט אמט}

\begin{hebrew}
  לורם איפסום דולור סיט אמט
\end{hebrew}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Answer (score 1):

Use [`bidi`](http://ctan.dcc.uchile.cl/macros/xetex/latex/bidi/bidi-doc.pdf)'s `\RLE` to correct the text direction:

```
%!TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{bidi}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Noto Sans Hebrew}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \begin{hebrew}\RLE{לורם איפסום דולור סיט אמט}\end{hebrew} 
\end{document}
```